# Using JavaScript and a dropdown to change page content

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

Google has plenty of results for *similar* problems, but after a day of searching, I still cannot figure this out.

I have a dropdown menu with six choices.

I have a switch statement with which I would like to evaluate the chosen item in the dropdown list to determine which document.write statements to execute.

Please keep in mind that the variables in the document write statements are defined before this block of code picks up. Also, the opening  tag exists much earlier in the code as well.

Thank you for your help.

```
    function handleSelect(account)
    {
        //var selectedAcct = document.getElementByName("acctTypes");

        document.write("<table><tbody>");

        switch(account)
        {

            case "View All":
                document.write(savings);
                document.write(checking);
                document.write(moneymkt);
                document.write(cdjumbo);
                document.write(cdsmall);
                document.write(iras);
                break;
            case "Certificates of Deposit (CDs)":
                document.write(cdjumbo);
                document.write(cdsmall);
                break;
            case "Individual Retirement Account (IRA)":
                document.write(iras);
                break;
            case "Money Market":
                document.write(moneymkt);
                break;
            case "Savings":
                document.write(savings);
                break;
            case "Checking":
                document.write(checking);
                break;
            default:
                document.write(savings);
                document.write(checking);
                document.write(moneymkt);
                document.write(cdjumbo);
                document.write(cdsmall);
                document.write(iras);
        }

        document.write("</tbody></table>");
    }


</script>

<form name="acctTypes" action=" ">
    <select name="acctDropdown" id="acctDropdown" onLoad="handleSelect(this.value)" onChange="handleSelect(this.value)">
        <option value="View All" selected>View All</option>
        <option value="Certificates of Deposit (CDs)">Certificates of Deposit (CDs)</option>
        <option value="Individual Retirement Account (IRA)">Individual Retirement Account (IRA)</option>
        <option value="Money Market">Money Market</option>
        <option value="Savings">Savings</option>
        <option value="Checking">Checking</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting when you try this?

Comment: I don't see what your problem is. For example, when you run it, what do you get? and what do you expect to get?

Comment: I'm not getting an error at all, as far as I can tell. The page loads with the dropdown, without the table, and when I select a different dropdown item, it appears to do nothing.

Comment: The variables inside of the document.write statements form different tables, depending on the combination of statements executed. My expectation is to see the table composed of all of the different tables when the page loads and then to see the smaller table parts depending on the dropdown choice I select.

Comment: And what are you currently seeing when you run the code?   Is it displaying one table only?  Or no tables?  Is it updating when you change the drop down?

Comment: It is displaying no tables and it does not change when I change the dropdown.

Comment: Is that behavior consistent across browsers/versions?  Are you certain handleSelect() is being called properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems from the comments that you are lacking an element to show the tables in.

Try adding a div element to the page in the position you want the table, and then setting the innerHTML of the div to be the table html you wish to display.

so create a div like

```
<div id="myTableContainer"></div>
```

and change the script

```
case "Savings":
    document.getElementById("myTableContainer").innerHTML = savings
    break;
```

Here is a demo (Select savings and the table will appear)

```
<html>
    <body>
       <script>
          function handleSelect(account) {
            var savings = "<table><tr><td>test</td></tr></table>";
            switch(account)
            {
           case "Savings":
          document.getElementById("myTableContainer").innerHTML = savings
          break;
        }
         }
    </script>
    <select name="acctDropdown" id="acctDropdown" onLoad="handleSelect(this.value)" onChange="handleSelect(this.value)">
    <option value="View All" selected>View All</option>
    <option value="Certificates of Deposit (CDs)">Certificates of Deposit (CDs)</option>
    <option value="Individual Retirement Account (IRA)">Individual Retirement Account (IRA)</option>
    <option value="Money Market">Money Market</option>
    <option value="Savings">Savings</option>
    <option value="Checking">Checking</option>
</select>
 <div id="myTableContainer"></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, rabs. The variable savings, for example, is a series of concatenated strings that contain the table container. If I comment out everything but the document.write statements, the table works perfectly.

Comment: Am I defining the account variable properly?

Comment: You might need something more like "handleSelect(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"

Comment: The account variable will come through as selected value (becuase you have the onChange inline) you don't need to use the selectedIndex.

Comment: change all the document.write statements to document.getElementById("myTableContainer").innerHTML = and add that div myTableContainer to the page and it will work

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the issue is not in the way that the document.write statements are written. It's the way that I'm getting the value from the dropdown and evaluating it in the switch statement. If I create a boolean variable and assign it a value and write an if...else statement with different document.write statements executing depending on the value of the variable, it works perfectly. I think it's all in that variable. Am I really assigning the right value to the account variable? If not, how do I set account equal to whatever the user picked in the dropdown?

Comment: I was wrong, rabs. You were absolutely right! Thank you for your help! Now I'm trying to figure out how run the function for "View All" when the page loads. Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

As you've written this, I think your page would continue to grow with an additional table each time handleSelect() is called.  You might be better off defining an empty TABLE & TBODY tag statically and then setting its innerHTML instead of using document.write().

For example, below your form you'd have something like

```
<table><tbody id="myContent"></tbody></table>
```

And then your document.write() statements would instead be something like

```
document.getElementById("myContent").innerHTML = cdjumbo + cdsmall;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try to figure out how to do that. My tables vary in size, but I think I get what you're saying. I'm still afraid I can't figure out how to tell it which content to fill the table with.

Comment: If you're using a JavaScript framework like YUI or jQuery, there are tools included that would make this work (and its debugging) easier.  Even if you're not, you could benefit from browser tools like Firebug and the built-in dev tools included with IE9/Chrome to examine variables and/or step through your script.  And one of the most basic JS debugging tools of all (which I generally don't recommend unless you're out of other options) would be to stick alert() calls into your code.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I'm going to play around with it and incorporate your suggestions.